# How to validate Spaces, between alphanumeric inputs

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am validating my text box input using regEx. I have my condition like,"it may take either only characters or both alphanumeric inputs" but it should not take only numbers.

I am using this code for validation:

```
var regex=/^[0-9]*?[a-zA-Z]+|[a-za-Z]+?[0-9]*$/;

if(!regex.test(city)){
    $("#error").html("Please enter a city details Correctly");
}
```

Its works fine for my condition but the issue is, this even takes spaces between alphanumeric/characters'.
How to avoid spaces for my above condition.Please help me to get out from this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your regex into capturing or non-capturing group, so that it would do an exact line match or otherwise, it would do a partial match like your's.

```
^([0-9]*?[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+?[0-9]*)$
```

Comment: ^([0-9]*?[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+?[0-9]*)$ from this expression i fixed sir,the small change is in your second validation you mention   small a twice'[a-za-Z]',this not working.when i change small a to caps A,it gives result fine as i need... thanks for your help

Comment: yep, it's a typo. Nice catch.

Comment: The regex in the question is wrong itself !! try '1abc1' .

Comment: @PankajGoyal op says that the regex he posted was working well. We just put it into a capturing group, inorder to do a complete line match. I'll edit my regex if op asks for the above issue.

Comment: @AvinashRaj What you did is absolutely correct. But the posted regex is itself wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var regex=/^(\d*[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\d*)$/;
```

Comment: /^(\d*[a-zA-Z]+|[a-za-Z]+\d*)$/; this wont validate sir,one small change is /^(\d*[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\d*)$/ thanks for your showing interest to help me..thanks lot

Comment: To my eyes both regex are same

Comment: sir,really that is not working when you give regex like        /^[a-za-Z]$/ this..i think its happened while you typing.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Thanks for your edit. Didn't realize OP had `a-Z` instead of `A-Z` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:(?:[0-9]*?[a-zA-Z]+)|(?:[a-zA-Z]+?[0-9]*))$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/30

Comment: good work..demo link was awesome its helped me to get work out in various kind of situations..

Answer (score 1):

try out this :

```
var regex = /^([\d]*?[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\d]*|[a-zA-Z]+?[a-zA-Z\d]*)$/;
```

Comment: its helped me to get out in another one problem that i not asked.. Good Work

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var regex=/^(?:(?:[0-9]*?[a-zA-Z]+)|(?:[a-zA-Z]+?[0-9]*))$/;
var city = "bangalore east";
if(!regex.test(city)){
    alert("Please type valid city");
} else {
    alert(city);
}
```